# communicating only few values from one angular component to another component

Tags: angular

I am new to developing web applications using angular. I am developing a e commerce web page. I have built a shopping cart(in component named"product component") which contain product details such as total cost and quantity. this works fine(increasing and decreasing of the quantity and total cost).

Now i developed another page for checkout and payment(shopping component) where i want to add product details for confirmation. so i want to display the values "Total cost","quantity" from "product component" in my shopping components. the values in "shopping component" should be changed when the values in "product component are changed" and they should be same.

I have tried using parent and child method. but the problem is when i define child component in parent component whole html is rendering instead of only required fields.

I have also tried using common service between components but it does not work fine or i have missed something.

```
  </div>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" id="decrease" value="DecreaseValue" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-success btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field=""  (click)="decreaseValue()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
              </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" id="number" name="quantity"  class="form-control input-number" value="{{value}}">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" id="increase" value="Increase Value" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field=""  (click)="increaseValue()">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
              </button>
          </span> </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="my-0">Total cost in Euros  </h6>
            <p>{{price | currency : "€"  }}</p> 
          </li>
```

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private ps: ProductShopService
        ) { this.value = this.ps.value,
          this.price = this.ps.price}
```

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private ps: ProductShopService
        ) { this.value = this.ps.value,
          this.price = this.ps.price}
```

```
    export class ProductShopService {
      // shopping cart start
      value: number  = 1;
      price: number  = 20;
     paypalLoad: boolean;


     increaseValue(){
       this.value= ++this.value;
       this.price= 20*this.value;
     }

     decreaseValue(){
       if(this.value < 2 ){
         this.value = 1
         }else{
           this.value = --this.value;
           }

       //this.value= --this.value;
       this.price= 20*this.value;
     }
      constructor() { }
    }
```

Please guide me through this problem.

Comment: Are you using any kind of backend api service that is storing any values in a database or is it only a front end?

Comment: I haven`t developed any backend service yet. first i want to check whether it is possible to do in front end. i want to route my shopping cart to checkout page when a button is clicked and the values should transfer from one component to another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the values localy. Try using the variables from the service in the template aswell as the methods. Also i would suggest you use ngModel directive instead of injecting the value directly into the input, that is if two way databing is required.

```
  </div>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" id="decrease" value="DecreaseValue" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-success btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field=""  (click)="ps.decreaseValue()">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
            </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" id="number" name="quantity"  class="form-control input-number" value="{{ps.value}}" [(ngModel)]="ps.value">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" id="increase" value="Increase Value" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field=""  (click)="ps.increaseValue()">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
              </button>
          </span> </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="my-0">Total cost in Euros  </h6>
            <p>{{ps.price | currency : "€"  }}</p> 
          </li>
```

Comment: No problem :) Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values on the front end easily I would use a service. As long as you are trying to access this data after navigating to a whole new page this should work. Just create a service and add class variables for the data you want to access. Then add functions to set and access these variables. To do this just create a class and put the @Injectable() decorator above the class definition.
That would look like this

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  someDataToComunicate;
  
  SetDataToComunicate(data) {
    this.someDataToComunicate = data;
  }
  GetDataToComunicate() {
    return someDataToComunicate;
  }
}
```

Then include the class in providers on your app.module.ts file. Then in any class you should be able to write something like this

```js
someProductData;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
}

someFunction() {
  this.someProductData = dataService.GetDataToComunicate();
}
```

Then it should be accessible in that component assuming it was previously set in some component prior to navigating to that page.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to look is behavioursubject http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject

Answer (score -1):

I don't know wha you do it this way, but you should not store values like price and values in the frontend. This should be stored in the backend. Because if you reload the app the values are reseted.

But back to your question, you should use a behavioursubject inside the service and subscribe to it in your components. So you always get the latest value